# Convert hex colour to HCL

Tags: r, colors

Given a character vector of some hexadecimal colour codes:

```r
hcl(h = c(0, 120, 240), c = 35, l = 85)
#> [1] "#FFC5D0" "#BBDEB1" "#B8D8F8"
```

How can I find their HCL representation?

Expected result:

```r
cbind(h = c(0, 120, 240), c = 35, l = 85)
#>        h  c  l
#> [1,]   0 35 85
#> [2,] 120 35 85
#> [3,] 240 35 85
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`decode_colour()` from the
[**farver** package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=farver) can be used to do this directly:

```r
library(farver)

hex <- hcl(h = c(0, 120, 240), c = 35, l = 85)

decode_colour(hex, to = "hcl")
#>             h        c        l
#> [1,] 359.3883 35.09095 84.86854
#> [2,] 120.2448 34.65261 84.98657
#> [3,] 239.3602 34.63943 85.03581
```

The result is not exact, but close enough.